# Set Size mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, responsive-design

may someone explain me why when i emulate this code with Google Chrome for a Mobile as Galaxy s3 it gives me the good size (640x360) but when i try to load it on my Galaxy s5 ou whatever , it does not give me same size than the emulator.

(I'll do an update with html if needed) Thanks a lot :)

```
function fitElementWithWidth(newWidth, element, baseElementWidth, baseElementHeight)
{
    newWidth+=10;

    if(newWidth>baseElementWidth)
        newWidth = baseElementWidth;

    element.style.width = newWidth+"px";
    element.style.height = (newWidth*baseElementHeight/baseElementWidth)+"px";

    return getViewport().width/baseElementWidth;
}

function fitElementWithHeight(newHeight, element, baseElementWidth, baseElementHeight)
{
    if(newHeight>baseElementHeight)
        newHeight = baseElementHeight;

    element.style.height = newHeight+"px";
    element.style.width =   (newHeight*baseElementWidth/baseElementHeight)+"px";

    var resizeLevel = getViewport().height/baseElementHeight;

    if(resizeLevel>1)
        resizeLevel = 1;

    if(baseElementWidth>getViewport().width/resizeLevel)
    {   
        return fitElementWithWidth(getViewport().width*resizeLevel/resizeLevel, element, baseElementWidth, baseElementHeight);
    }
    else
    {
        return resizeLevel;
    }
}

function centerElement(element)
{
    element.style["left"] = "50%";
    element.style["top"] = "50%";

    element.style["margin-left"] = (-parseFloat(element.style.width)/2)+"px";
    element.style["marginLeft"] = (-parseFloat(element.style.width)/2)+"px";

    element.style["margin-top"] = (-parseFloat(element.style.height)/2)+"px";
    element.style["marginTop"] = (-parseFloat(element.style.height)/2)+"px";
}

function setLocalPosition(element, parent, top, left, scale)
{
    element.style["left"] = "50%";
    element.style["top"] = "50%";

    element.style["margin-left"] = (parseFloat(parent.style["margin-left"])+left*scale)+"px";
    element.style["marginLeft"] = (parseFloat(parent.style["marginLeft"])+left*scale)+"px";

    element.style["margin-top"] = (parseFloat(parent.style["margin-top"])+top*scale)+"px";
    element.style["marginTop"] = (parseFloat(parent.style["marginTop"])+top*scale)+"px";
}

function setLocalScale(element, baseWidth, baseHeight, scale)
{
    element.style.width = baseWidth*scale+"px";
    element.style.height = baseHeight*scale+"px";
}

function getViewport() 
{
    var viewPortWidth;
    var viewPortHeight;

    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') 
    {
        if(detectmob())
        {
            viewPortWidth = window.screen.width;
            console.log(viewPortWidth);
            viewPortHeight = window.screen.height;
            console.log(viewPortHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth;
            viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight;
        }
    }

    // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
    && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
    'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
        viewPortWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        viewPortHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }

    // older versions of IE
    else {
        viewPortWidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
        viewPortHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
    }

    if(window.orientation)
    {
        if(window.orientation==-90 || window.orientation==90) 
        {
            //device was inverted... compute again
            console.log("paysage");
            var lastHeight = viewPortHeight;
            viewPortHeight = viewPortWidth;
            viewPortWidth = lastHeight;
        }
    }

    return {width:viewPortWidth, height:viewPortHeight};
}

function getParentViewPort()
{
    var viewPortWidth;
    var viewPortHeight;

    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
    if (typeof parent.window.innerWidth != 'undefined') 
    {
        if(detectmob())
        {
            viewPortWidth = parent.window.screen.width,
            viewPortHeight = parent.window.screen.height
            console.log(viewPortWidth);
            console.log(viewPortHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            viewPortWidth = parent.window.innerWidth,
            viewPortHeight = parent.window.innerHeight
        }
    }

    // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
    else if (typeof parent.document.documentElement != 'undefined'
    && typeof parent.document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
    'undefined' && parent.document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
        viewPortWidth = parent.document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        viewPortHeight = parent.document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }

    // older versions of IE
    else {
        viewPortWidth = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
        viewPortHeight = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
    }

    if(window.orientation)
    {
        if(window.orientation==-90 || window.orientation==90) 
        {
            //device was inverted... compute again
            var lastHeight = viewPortHeight;
            viewPortHeight = viewPortWidth;
            viewPortWidth = lastHeight;
        }
    }

    return {width:viewPortWidth, height:viewPortHeight};
}

function detectmob() 
{ 
    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[On Emulator](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/52/1450962663-1.png)
[On My Mobile](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/52/1450962663-2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wish the page to be like as if it was made for this device, use the following meta tag in the head section.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Now everything that you add, keep its width in percentage like width:100%  and so on.
Why put an extra load calculating the width and height. Different browsers, specially the ones with mobile have lot of issues. This one meta tag solves all I ever faced.

Comment: i had already : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> :s

Comment: here's the link if u want to try it on your cellphone : http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/Carte_D_Or/html/index.html

Comment: yes! that's great, but this only means the starting. Try adding the maximum-scale=1.0 and this would not let things run out of screen. Also do things in percentage. Also let me try

Comment: Didn't change anything at all :s

Comment: The widths are in pixels.

Comment: What i'm supposed to change ?

Comment: I'm glad you find my problem , May you help me now ? :D i have nowhere any width in Pixels

Comment: I mean that you can convert tings to fluid layout.
like you may represent width: 1000px; as width: 90%.
you just need to do a few calculations. And yes... adding that meta tag did make some change in the default browser of android.

Comment: An emulator claims to be a mobile and tries representing a real mobile, but after every argument, its a virtual application in a PC. so there are a few setbacks.
There are very few but still there are incidents where an output on a real mobile and an emulator differs. Thus in best practice, before any delivery, check the product on any random mobile phone.